# basic question about setting up event listeners in jquery

Tags: jquery

I come from as3 and I'm a bit lost with jQuery. 
I have the feeling I haven't grasped the concept of how events work with jQuery, or javascript for that matters. I'm trying to do this:

```
animation 1 ends --> load image --> animation 2 starts
```

By now I'm doing this through the complete:function(){} parameter in .animate(). It works, but is not very flexible.

How is it possible to set up a scenario like this?:

*

```
addEventListener(when animation 1 ends, do whatever)

addEventListener(when image loading ends, do whatever)

addEventListener(when animation 2 ends, do whatever)
```

*

I' tried using .bind() and .live(), something like   $(window-document-div-etc).bind('load','animation stored in a variable', etc) with no results. 
Any suggestions on how to do it?

Thanks in advance

---

First of all, thanks everybody for your help.

*Sorry for using this "answer your question" feature, I haven't beenn able to use the "add comment" link, and, after all, I find a little silly pasting the same answer to everybody. If there is some kind any kind of moderator around, please move this to wherever it should be moved.*

Please excuse my lack of a proper technical language. This "callback functions" approach is the one I've used at first, and it works fine, but the resulting code is not very reusable.

I would like to know how is it possible to write something more respectful with encapsulation, something like this:

```
Image A is loaded, event is dispatched "IMAGE LOADED"

Totally unrelated Object B has a listener for the "IMAGE LOADED" event, so receives  the event and processes it through its method bDoesThis().


Totally unrelated Object C has a listener for the "IMAGE LOADED" event, so receives the event and processes it through its method cDoesThat().
```

Thanks again!

Comment: Please change your question's title to reflect the question and not the ease of answering it.

Comment: Well, actually I don't know if its easy or difficult to answer. It's about setting up and dispatching events, which I think is a pretty basic feature of any lenguage, so yes, it's about the basics. If I get a better idea on how to reflect this in the title, I will change it accordingly.

Comment: THANKS EVERYBODY FOR YOUR HELP; DIDN'T KNOW HOW TO ANSWER YOU ALL, AND DROPPED THE MESSAGE STARTING WITH Sorry for using this "answer your question" feature.
SORRY FOR THE DISTURBANCE

Answer (score 2):

I think you're referring to [Callback Functions](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:How_jQuery_Works#Callback_and_Functions).

```
$('div').animate({
    left: 50
}, 500, function() {
    // animation completed.
    $(this).hide();
});
```

---

```
$('img').bind('load', function() {
    // Callback (image has loaded)
    $(this).fadeIn(200);       
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You bind events to objects that you obtain using a $(selector) format, for instance $(document) or $('#yourElementid') and add event handlersr using `bind` or `live`. Live has the advantage that any newly created elements that match the selector automatically get bound using your event handler. For example,

```
 $('.clickme').bind('click', function()
    {//event handler.
      $(".block:first").animate({"left": "+=50px"}, "slow" , "swing", function(){
        //animation 1 ends.do whatever in callback
      });
    };
```

You can alternatively just use `$('.clickme').click(function(){});` as a shortcut instead of the cumbersome `$('.clickme').bind('click',function(){})` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You would use callback functions, and an event listener for the image like this:

```
// select what you want to animate, and do some animation
// set a callback function to execute upon completion
$('div').animate({width:100},2000,function(){
    // in the callback - create a new IMG element
    $('div').html('<img id="newImage" src="http://farm7.static.flickr.com/6085/6027474363_42050547b2_b.jpg" />')
    // set an event listener for your IMG element
    $('#newImage').load(function(){
        // do second animation
        $('div').animate({width:800},2000)
    })
})
```

You can see a demo of this code here: http://jsfiddle.net/fePzu/